# Android get DNS services from a different subnet

Tags: java, android, dns, jmdns

Ok I've been looking around for ways to get DNS services from a local subnet but can't seem to get it working.

So far I can get the local DNS ip's when I connect to the wifi with the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Class<?> SystemProperties = Class
                    .forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
            Method method = SystemProperties.getMethod("get",
                    new Class[] { String.class });

            for (String name : new String[] { "net.dns1", "net.dns2",
                    "net.dns3", "net.dns4", }) {
                String value = (String) method.invoke(null, name);
                if (value != null && !"".equals(value)
                        && !servers.contains(value))
                    servers.add(value);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        for (String s : servers) {
            Log.v("ERRORID", s);
        }
```

And it returns the following as strings:

```
10.10.10.204
172.19.2.10
```

From here I want to query each DNS ip for all of it's services, but don't know how.

EDIT:
I've tried using jmDNS but to no luck

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("172.19.2.10");
JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(addr);
jmdns.addServiceListener("_http._tcp.local.", new SampleListener());
```

SampleListener() is:

```
    static class SampleListener implements ServiceListener {
    @Override
    public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
        Log.v("ERRORID", "Service added   : " + event.getName() + "."
                + event.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent event) {
        Log.v("ERRORID", "Service removed : " + event.getName() + "."
                + event.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) {
        Log.v("ERRORID", "Service resolved: " + event.getInfo());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to salve this?

Answer (score 0):

Jmdns.create does only bind to a local network interface. Not to a remote DNS server. Use an IP of any network interface of your pc, jmds will operate only on this interface.
You do not have to query the servers for services. They should publish them automatically and you should get an serviceAddedEvent call.